# Increase in Memory usage when dispatch is called in a setTimeout loop

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have some functionality in place where dispatch is called continuously to pull data from DB.  The code looks similar to snippet below:

```
componentWillMount()
  {
    this.startPoll();
  }

  startPoll() {
    console.log('StartPoll called!');
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'TEST'});
    setTimeout(this.startPoll.bind(this), 150000);
  }
```

With this in place, I see that memory usage in Chrome ( Shift + Escape ) keeps rising and reaches several hundred MBs and eventually the application becomes unresponsive. Same is the case in other browsers.

If I call a regular function instead of dispatch in the loop, I don't see this increase in memory usage.

I am new to javascript and react/redux, so might be missing something basic. Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue was that I have DevTools enabled in the project. As expected, Devtools keeps track of every state change since launch of the application. Turning it off resolved this issue!!